# The method 'SignInWithTwitter isn't defined in the class flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, twitter-login

im trying to add Twitter sign-in method in my project.i have got few lines of code online when i try it in my project its throwing me error. can someone help me in this.

Here's my code:

```
 Future<FirebaseUser> loginWithTwitter() async {
  var twitterLogin = new TwitterLogin(
    consumerKey: 'Y2MyConsumerKeyYKX',
    consumerSecret: 'xYXUMyConsumerSecretKeyjFAJZMyConsumerSecretKeyS3i',
  );

  final TwitterLoginResult result = await twitterLogin.authorize();

  switch (result.status) {
    case TwitterLoginStatus.loggedIn:
      var session=result.session;
      final AuthCredential credential= TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential(
          authToken: session.token,
          authTokenSecret: session.secret
      );
      FirebaseUser firebaseUser=(await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
      print("twitter sign in"+firebaseUser.toString());
      break;
    case TwitterLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
      break;
    case TwitterLoginStatus.error:
      break;
  }
  return null;
}
```

The error is with the command SignInWithTwitter and Debug print.can someone help me in this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUA6M.jpg)

[image]

Comment: After ```pub get``` run ```flutter clean``` and run again.

Comment: no sir it didn't work

Comment: i have added a screenshot of the error is kindly check it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FirebaseAuth` does not contain a method called `signInWithTwitter`, if you want to sign in using twitter then you need to use the class [`TwitterAuthProvider`](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/lib/src/auth_provider/twitter_auth_provider.dart)

For example:

```
switch (result.status) {
  case TwitterLoginStatus.loggedIn:
    var session=result.session;
    final AuthCredential credential= TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential(
      authToken: session.token,
      authTokenSecret: session.secret
    );
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser=(await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
    print("twitter sign in"+firebaseUser.toString());
    break;
  case TwitterLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
    break;
  case TwitterLoginStatus.error:
    break;
}
```

Inside the `getCredential` you can add the `authToken` and `authTokenSecret` and then pass the variable as an argument to `signInWithCredentials`

Comment: can you check my updated code and tell me how can i add authToken and authTokenSecret in it please

Comment: What is the issue

Comment: i'm being redirected to this page and after this when im logging in the database is not displaying the username

Comment: This page is asking you to authorize twitter

Comment: I account which I'm using to login that accounts username is not displaying in the database

Comment: It should display an email not username check this https://liongueststudios.com/twitter-login-authentication-using-firebase-in-android/#Solving_the_twitter_email_field_appearing_empty_in_Firebase_Authentication

Comment: It's not displaying anything

Comment: Check my screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204896/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-myname).