# What is the purpose of FirebaseAuth.signOut method

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement Firebase Authentication and code is working, and at logoff I see no value in calling firebase_auth.signOut(), the net effect is same.

```
FirebaseAuth _firebase_auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();



GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn().catchError((onError) {
          debugPrint("Error $onError");
        });

final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

AuthResult authResult;
  try {
    authResult = await _firebase_auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  } on Exception catch (e) {
   debugPrint('$e');
    return null;
  }

FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;
// do whatever
```

and at time of logOff

```
await _firebase_auth.signOut().then((response) {
      isLogged = false;
      setState(() {});
    });

GoogleSignInAccount gSignOut = await _googleSignIn.signOut();
```

But if I don't call **_firebase_auth.signOut**() ,the sign off still happens, so I am not able to understand why I need to call it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't call `_firebase_auth.signOut()` then the same user will still be signed in when you enter the application again. You can check if user is logged in using the following:

```
if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser() != null) {
    // signed in
} else {

}
```

without calling `signOut()` then `currentUser()` will not be null and user will still be sign in.

Also if u are checking the user outside of `.then` method then it will be null since it is `asynchronous`. In your code you are actually using two signin, the Google signin and the Firebase one.

The Firebase `signOut` will sign you out of all auth provider so if u use Google and twitter then you will get signed out of both.

---

You are using a different plugin. The class `GoogleSignin` is from this plugin:

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_sign_in/google_sign_in/lib/google_sign_in.dart

Comment: if I do googleSignIn.signOut() then the currentUser becomes null without doing _firebase_auth.signOut()

Comment: Google signin is from this plugin https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_sign_in/google_sign_in/lib/google_sign_in.dart?

Comment: (1/2)If u are checking the user outside of `then` then it will be null since it is asynchronous. Also I'm not sure why you are using two sign in. The Google signin and the Firebase one?. Also the Firebase signOut will sign you out of all auth provider so if u use Google and twitter then you will get signed out of both

Comment: (2/2)But in your case, you are using a completely different plugin to sign in..

Comment: please point me to a simple but elegant solution for firebase authentication with google, phone , email and facebook

Comment: which one is the correct plugin, can you please provide url/name

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth this is how u login using twitter with firebase https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489207/the-method-signinwithtwitter-isnt-defined-in-the-class-flutter/59489297#59489297